Error: TypeError: request is not iterable, Gemini API
im making clone of gemini AI using react and javascript, at first glance it seems works, but after i inspect my project at the browser i got these errors, can anyone explain to me? newbie here
@google_generative-ai.js?v=1f858b71:559 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: request is not iterable
    at formatNewContent (@google_generative-ai.js?v=1f858b71:559:32)
    at ChatSession.sendMessage (@google_generative-ai.js?v=1f858b71:730:24)
    at async run (gemini.js:24:18)

this is my current code
import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";

const apiKey = "AIzaSyDBBrhCK33iSPdt8RXJF6ev_6pPBthW57w";
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(apiKey);

const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({
  model: "gemini-1.5-flash",
});

const generationConfig = {
  temperature: 1,
  topP: 0.95,
  topK: 40,
  maxOutputTokens: 8192,
  responseMimeType: "text/plain",
};

async function run(prompt) {
  const chatSession = model.startChat({
    generationConfig,
    history: [],
  });

  const result = await chatSession.sendMessage(prompt);
  console.log(result.response.text());
}

run();

export default run;



When I saw your script, prompt is undefined. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. So, how about giving the value to prompt as follows?
From:
run();

To:
run("Describe about you."); // Please set your text by replacing the sample text "Describe about you.".


When I tested this modification, I confirmed that the modified script worked.

